# Как вывести результат в переменную который был расчитан в expect

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, shell

Как я могу передать echo true или echo false в переменную result

```
result=false

login=$1
pass=$2
ip=$3
port=$4
pathSftp=$5

#expect \"(yes/no)?\"
#send \"yes\n\"
expect -c "spawn sftp -oPort=$port $login@$ip
expect \"password:\"
send \"$pass\n\"
expect \"sftp>\"
send \"cd $pathSftp\n\"
expect \"sftp>\"
send \"[ -e checkFile ]\n\"
expect \"sftp>\"
send \"if (($?==0)); then echo true; else echo false; fi\n\"
expect \"sftp>\"
send \"bye\n\"
interact"
```

Comment: переформулируйте вопрос, если не сложно, иначе ответ `result=$6`. но это же то, что вам нужно?

Comment: А почему именно expect? Какое-то сетевое оборудование?

Comment: `result=$?` не пойдёт?

Comment: Зачем так сложно?! Просто заход через sftp не работает?